# Unable to Post data using Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am gettting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyyEY.jpg) although I am giving proper string in Text and Title fields.I don't know what are the reasons,However i am able to post the values of remaining three fields(author,Created_date,publish_date).

Serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from blog.models import Post
from django.utils import timezone
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator

class blogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('author','title', 'text','created_date','published_date')
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',null=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
   published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,null=True)

   def publish(self):
       self.published_date = timezone.now()
       self.save()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

views.py

```
from blog.models import Post
from .serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer,blogSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets,status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

class blogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = blogSerializer
```

here i am posting the data.

```
    @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
    def blog_list(request):
       if request.method=='GET':
           my_blog=Post.objects.all()
           serializers=blogSerializer(my_blog,Many=True)
           return JsoResponse(serializers.data,safe=False)

       elif request.method=='POST':
           data=JSONParser().parse(request)
           serializers=blogSerializer(data=data)
           if serializers.is_valid():
              serializer.save()
              return JsonResponse(serializers.data,status=201)
           return JsonResponse(serializers.errors,status=400)
```

Comment: You're getting an error because text and title are required and are empty. If you want them to be optional add `blank=True, null=True` to the model.

Comment: @Razzildinho he claims that he provides a proper string for both fields.

Comment: No, I am giving proper string in these two fields but still it throwing the same error.

Comment: Did you try that only with the browsable API? What happens if you try that in the shell, something like: `curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title": "Some title", "text": "Some text"}' http://localhost:8000`. If needed change `http://localhost:8000`.

Comment: i suggest to overwrite the create function (or event the post function) and print debug messages. For example print request.data

Comment: @cezar yes i am only trying with browsable API and now i tried with the curl on shell but its printing html page on the shell.what does it mean??

Comment: Probably an error, normally it should have returned JSON.

Comment: You are not showing how your *post* the data

Comment: @e4c5 can you please check now?

Comment: you have added a view that accepts an HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a unit test to test this functionality. It looks like none of your post data is getting to the serializer otherwise the valid fields would have been repopulated once you submit the form and the for is returned with errors. The title and text fields are also the only fields which are required/do not have a default value.

If you are using some form of decorator(or something similar) on the view which accesses `request.data`, this might be what is causing the issue. Since rest framework modifies `request.POST` when populating `request.data`

Comment: The data of other three fields(author,Created_date,publish_date) are getting to the serializer.

Comment: How did you test that? In your screenshot, the form errors are displayed because the form was submitted and validation failed. If validation failed only on text and title the other fields would still have the data which you entered when you initially submitted the form. You are not seeing required errors for the additional fields since the author is nullable and the date fields have default values specified

Comment: I would drop a `pdb` statement inside the viewset's create method and have a look at the `request.data` content